# Return images via PHP and set as src with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, file

I have some problems when I try to display multiple images (well it doesn't work for one image so multiple is impossible), and what I'm doing is with my function of AJAX to recover from my db, all the images location string that are in the table images. Then it calls another function called *setImages()* which receives those strings of the image locations and I use iterate over the strings (using jQuery's *.each()*) to trigger an AJAX request that calls a php script named `image.php?img=[data]`. *data* is the string containing the image location, so I have something like the code below:

**The problem is that `setImages()` of my js, doesn't show the images**

#### the PHP file:

```
<?php

    $init="/var/Imagenes/cursos/";
    $img=$_GET['img'];
    $path=$init.$img;
    echo $path;
//el path debe ser autores/ or cursos/
    $name="azure";
/*
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("X-Sendfile: $path");
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename='archivos'");
*/
//el nombre de la base de datos de la imagen
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
if((isset($path)&& !is_null($path))){
    header("X-Sendfile: $path");
    if(strpos( $img, ".png" )||strpos( $img, ".PNG" )){
        header("Content-Type: image/PNG;base64");
    }
    elseif(strpos( $img, ".jpg" )||strpos( $img, ".JPG" )){
        header("Content-Type: image/jpg;base64");
    }
    elseif(strpos( $img, ".jpeg" )||strpos( $img, ".JPEG" )){
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg;base64");
    }
    else{
        return "error.jpg";
    }
    $newimg=rand(1000 , 9999 );
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; fileimg= $newimg-$img");
    exit();
}
else{
    echo "no se pudo realizar la consulta";}
```

#### JS code:

functions *listImgCursos* works fine...

```
function listImgCursos(identificador) {
           var resultado= $.ajax({
                url: consultaBasica,
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                data : { action: "imgCursos"}
            }).then(
                function(data){// Success
                    var flagErrFound = false;
                    var nf404 = "" ;
                        $.each(data,
                            function(index,datos){
                                if((datos['id']===null)||(datos['img']=="")||(datos['img']==null)){
                                    nf404 = datos['id'];
                                    flagErrFound= true;
                                }//if close
                            }//function close
                        )//each close
                        if(flagErrFound===true){
                            error = {error: "CX02", msj: "Failed to get data from records.", data: nf404 };
                            return $.Deferred().reject(error);
                            }
                        else
                            return data;
                    },//function sucessful
                function(){// fail
                    error = {error: "CX01", msj: "Failed to execute ajax"};
                    return $.Deferred().reject(error);
                    }//function fail
                );//then;  
            resultado.done(
                function (data){//success
                   setImages(data);
                }//function DONE
            );
            resultado.fail(
                function(e){//function fail
                    console.log(e.msj + " "+ e.error + ":" + e.data );
                }//function FAIL)
            );  
    }
    function setImages(data){
    
    
        $.each(data, function (index, datos) {
            var temp="../classes/imagen.php?img="+encodeURIComponent(datos['img'])+"&t="+((new Date).getTime());
            console.log(temp); // returns something like: ../classes/imagen.php?img=curso-2561.jpg&t=1489074434134
            $.ajax({
                url: temp,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "image/jpg;base64",
                async:true,
              cache: false,
              success: function(datai){
                console.log(datai);
                    $('#pickimg').append('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + datai + '" />');
              },
              fail: function(){
    
              }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Awesome!  (Is there a problem?  If so, please describe.)

Comment: I would recommend not to load the image content with AJAX, instead set the `src` of your `<img>` to `image.php?img=[data]`

Comment: Can you please provide additional information other than 'does not show images'? A JS Fiddle, or a description of what happens on success() (if it is even being called, if there is a JS error, if the img gets appended, but it doesn't show, etc.)

Comment: Where did you find that _header_ tag (i.e. `header("Content-Disposition: inline; fileimg= $newimg-$img");`)? Have you used that in other places to return the image contents?

Comment: what is in datai ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that setImages() of my js, doesn't show the images

This is because of multiple reasons:

- The PHP code isn't actually returning the file contents. To do that, use a function like [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents), 
  [readfile()](http://php.net/readfile), etc. Also, the string should be base-64 encoded so use [base64_encode()](http://php.net/base64_encode).

  ```
  $newimg=rand(1000 , 9999 );
  header("Content-Disposition: inline; fileimg= $newimg-$img");
  echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($path));
  exit();
  ```
- This may be redundant with the first bullet, but the Syntax for header [*Content-Disposition*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) only contains three directives: *name*, *filename* and *filename**.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#Directives)</sup>. So that *fileimg* directive is invalid. That header *could* include the *filename* directive but because a string is being returned it would be useless:

  ```
  header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"$newimg-$img\"");
  ```
- In that sense it isn't really returning an image, so the headers for *Content-Type* are basically incorrect. Consequently, the AJAX call (using [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) should not specify the dataType (i.e. `dataType: "image/jpg;base64"` which wouldn't be dynamic anyway - for jpgs, pngs, etc). So remove that *dataType* option.

See a demonstratation of this with the modifications applied in [this phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/61vj-wpgm). Click the button labeled **Run - F9** - and then when the frame loads, click the button labeled *Update* to trigger an AJAX call to the PHP script which will load a PNG image and append it to the element with id attribute "*pickimg*".

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#Directives</sub>